# AlarmManager funcions on API 24 but not on API 28

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm using Androids `AlarmManager` to set off an event at 5 minute intervals.  This works fine on my api 24 phone but fails to function on my api 28 phone.  When running on the api 28 phone `dumpsys alarm` shows that the alarms are going off but the `JobIntentService` passed in their intent is never called.

So far I've tried different ways of setting the alarm, such as `setAndAllowWhileIdle` with no effect.  Running `dumpsys alarm` on the api 28 phone shows that the single shot `setAlarmWhileIdle` goes off but does not go off again as expected.  Similarly `setInexactRepeating` also goes off at the passed repeating interval.  Both do not call the passed `JobIntentService`.

```
public class DataUploadService extends JobIntentService
    implements DataClientManager.OnDataChangedListener {

private static final String TAG = "DataUploadService";
private static void LOG(String msg) { Log.d(TAG,msg); }
private static void LOGE(String msg) { Log.e(TAG,msg); }

public static final int DELAY_PERIOD = 5;

public static void initialize(Context context) {

    //parse minutes to get exact time
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE,DELAY_PERIOD);

    DataUploadService.setAlarm(context,calendar.getTimeInMillis());

}

public static void setAlarm(Context context, long millis) {

    clearAlarm(context);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DataUploadService.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millis,
            DELAY_PERIOD * 60 * 1000, alarmIntent);

}

public static void clearAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DataUploadService.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleWork(Intent intent) {

    LOGE("Data Acquisition Service has been called");
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    LOG(calendar.getTime().toString());

}
}
```

In my `MainActivity` i call `DataUploadService.initalize(this)`, after which i would expect to see in my system log `"Data Acquisition Service has been called"` at 5 minute intervals.  This happens as desired on my api 24 phone but does not on my api 28 phone.  I see no noticeable difference in the api for `AlarmManager` in the documentation.

**Update:**

I found that `set(int type, long triggerAtMillis, String tag, AlarmManager.OnAlarmListener listener, Handler targetHandler)` to work on my api level 28 device.  Both a null and non-null `Handler` seem to work.  This doesn't answer my question as to why `JobIntentService` no longer works but does provide a temporary work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is happening because you are scheduling the Alarm and starting a service when it expires.

Since services are background tasks, they are a bit more restricted now (from API26+)

So, I'm seeing two solutions:

**First Solution**

Create a Broadcast receiver (adding the intents to `AndroidManifest.xml` etc). So, after 5 minutes, that broadcast will receive the intent and that broadcast will start the service via:

AndroidManifest

```
<receiver
    android:name=".DataUploadBroadcast"
    android:exported="true"
    tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="MY_CUSTOM_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

BroadcastReceiver

```
public class DataUploadBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final int DELAY_PERIOD = 5;

    public void onReceive(Context receivedContext, Intent intent) {
        if("MY_CUSTOM_ACTION".equals(intent.getAction() {
            DataUploadService.enqueueWork(context, new Intent(context, DataUploadService.class);
        }
    }

    private static void setAlarm(Context context, long millis) {
        clearAlarm(context);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

         // Note the class is different now
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, DataUploadBroadcast.class);

        // Set action
        intent.setAction("MY_CUSTOM_ACTION");

        // Note the getBroadcast
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millis, DELAY_PERIOD * 60 * 1000, alarmIntent);
    }

    public static void initialize(Context context) {
        // call setAlarm
    }

    private static void clearAlarm(Context context) {
        // Clear the alarm
    }
}
```

DataUploadService

```
private static final int JOB_ID = 100;

public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
    // This is how you should start the job.. and not PendingIntent.getService(...)
    enqueueWork(context, DataUploadService.class, JOB_ID, work);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleWork(Intent intent) {
    LOGE("Data Acquisition Service has been called");
}
```

**Second solution**

Let the service starts as soon as the Activity request to. Then, during the `onHandleWork`, you put the service to sleep for 5 minutes:

```
public class DataUploadService extends JobIntentService
    implements DataClientManager.OnDataChangedListener {

    public static final int DELAY_PERIOD = 5;
    private static final int JOB_ID = 100;

    public static void initialize(Context context) {
        enqueueWork(context, DataUploadService.class, JOB_ID, new Intent(context, DataUploadService.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(Intent intent) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(DELAY_PERIOD * 60 * 1000);
            efectivellyExecuteWork()
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOGE("ERROR");
        }
}

private void efectivellyExecuteWork() {
    LOGE("Data Acquisition Service has been called");
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    LOG(calendar.getTime().toString());
}
```

In this second solution, I just put the thread to sleep for 5 minutes. You can add some logic if you need to update that timer in case user opens the activity before it expires etc..
You can store a calendar instance with a date in the future, for example. This way, the thread sleeps until that date is reached. This would allow you to update the calendar date when necessary (acting like clearing/recreating the event);

Something like:

```
try {
    while(futureDate.getTimeInMillis() > Calendar.getInstance.getTimeInMillis()) {
        Thread.sleep(futureDate.getTimeInMillis() - Calendar.getInstance.getTimeInMillis());
    }
    efectivellyExecuteWork()
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    LOGE("ERROR");
}
```